# Cronjob fails with “ipset not found” but runs flawlessly on command-line

Tags: linux, bash, cron

When I call a script from a (`root`) cronjob it fails with the message 'ipset not found'. Here is the problematic script line:

```
for i in $(cat /etc/cn.zone); do ipset -A china $i; done
```

Some lines before in the script this command is called:

```
ipset -N china hash:net
```

So the ipset in question was actually created.

If I run this script from root's home directory it runs flawlessly through.

Any idea as to what might cause the error?

Answer (score 2):

## Your script is not seeing your environment variables when run as a cron job.

> I call a script from a (`root`) cronjob and it fails with the message 'ipset not found'…

Are you running this script as a Bash script; which is what most shell scripts nowadays are?

If so then change your script’s first line from

```
#!/bin/bash
```

To this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

Adding the `-l` tells Bash to run as if it had been invoked as a login shell. And if the Bash script is run via the login shell in that cron job, all of the environment variables—and other items—that are normally set via the login shell will be available to that Bash script, thus allowing `ipset` to run as expected.

---

Another trick you can do is use `which` within a Bash variable like this; you clearly are using that for `$(cat /etc/cn.zone)` so the mechanism is similar:

```
$(which ipset)
```

And in your script change your line to this:

```
for i in $(cat /etc/cn.zone); do $(which ipset) -A china $i; done
```

What that will do is—by using `which`—give your script the full path to `ipset` (something like `/sbin/ipset`) on whatever system you are running this on. And then the setting of it as a parsed variable via `$()` will let the script itself run it.

But since you use `ipset` elsewhere in your script, I would recommend—if you use this `which` method—that you refactor your script to set `ipset` as a variable like this near the top of your script:

```
ipset_bin=$(which ipset);
```

And then call your commands like this:

```
$ipset_bin -N china hash:net
```

And this:

```
for i in $(cat /etc/cn.zone); do $ipset_bin -A china $i; done
```

Comment: +1 Good answer (better than mine).

Answer (score 0):

Your shell knows where to find executables like `ipset` by looking in your `PATH`,
which is set by your environment, but `cron` does not share that same environment.

Adding this at the top of the `crontab` (or your script) should tell it where
to find the commands just as you expect:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: While this works, it relies mainly on setting a predefined `PATH` list which might be different on different systems and setups. The best solution is to set the Bash script to pass environment variables via the `-l` flag like this in the first line: `#!/bin/bash -l`